# Javascript object locking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, locking, deferred

I am running into a strange problem with not being able to update properties on an object that is returned as part of a deferred promise.

```
// Update or Insert status information into the idr_status table
this.updateStatus = function (idrInspData, statusId, submitting)
{
    var def = new $.Deferred();
    self.getIdrStatus (idrInspData.idr_date).done (function (idrStatus)
    {
        //status record exists for the day update record
        idrStatus.status_msg_id = statusId;
        idrStatus.submitted = submitting ? 1 : 0;
        idrStatus.modified = 1;

        idrStatus.action_needed = statusId.search('+') != -1 ? true : false;

        // update the status
        self.db.updateRecord (self.idrStatusTableName, idrStatus).always (
            function (updateResult)
            {
                def.resolve(true);
            });

    }).fail (function (result)
    {
       def.reject(result);
    });

    return (def.promise ());
}
```

The **idrStatus** object is returned from a SQLite resultset and then converted to a plain JS object then resolved to the done function above. The object comes in but any attempt to edit the properties are simply ignored and the same object is passed **Unchanged** to the **updateRecord** function. I am puzzled? Why would the object be locked?

Comment: did you debug inside the `.done` to see if `idrStatus` is assigned at that time? because I don't think it was lucked rather not assigned yet from the db when entered the `.done`. and forgive me if this is absurd :D is been long time since worked on the SQLITE

Comment: Yes I debugged inside the done. Thats where I noticed that the object properties values were not be re-assigned. Super weird? I guess I could try to create a new object reference/copy inside the done. See if that works but I dont think that I should have to.

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure if you can edit the resultset! as you said you probably should receive the data in another object if you wanna change it!

Comment: Yep that was it! resultset must be locked in the SQLite JS API. So converting each row to a plain JS object works. My function before was pushing the resultset into an object array without converting each row. Still kinda freaky, nothing in their docs indicate that the resultset is locked.